# Yup validate array of objects contains at most one object where property = value

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using Formik's `FieldArray` to add objects dynamically to an array, rendering additional form elements as objects are `push()`ed to the array.

My schema looks like this:

```js
const EMAIL_SCHEMA = Yup.object().shape({
  address: Yup.string().email().required( 'E-mail address is required.' ),
  isPreferredContact: Yup.boolean()
})

const SCHEMA = Yup.object().shape({
  emails: Yup.array()
             .of( EMAIL_SCHEMA )
             .ensure()
             .compact( v => !v.address )
             .required( 'At least one e-mail address is required.' )
})
```

For each e-mail input, there is a corresponding checkbox to indicate if it is the preferred contact e-mail address. No e-mail addresses are *required* to be marked as preferred.

What I would like to do is validate that the array contains **at most one** object where `isPreferredContact` is `true`. If there are 3 e-mail objects in the array and `isPreferredContact` is `false` for all of them, that's a valid state. That is to say:

```js
let values = [
  {address: '1@email.com', isPreferredContact: false},
  {address: '2@email.com', isPreferredContact: false},
  {address: '3@email.com', isPreferredContact: false}
] // OK

let values = [
  {address: '1@email.com', isPreferredContact: true},
  {address: '2@email.com', isPreferredContact: false},
  {address: '3@email.com', isPreferredContact: false}
] // OK

let values = [
  {address: '1@email.com', isPreferredContact: true},
  {address: '2@email.com', isPreferredContact: true},
  {address: '3@email.com', isPreferredContact: false}
] // Invalid
```

I see this answer

[Yup: deep validation in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197551/yup-deep-validation-in-array-of-objects)

shows that the `compact()` method can be used to validate for **at least one**, because if after removing "falsy" values from the array, the array is empty, then it's easy to treat the schema key as invalid.

There's nothing I can see, though, for validating that the array contains **at most** one object with a property = value predicate.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After poking through Yup's issues in GitHub, staring at the API docs (the doc for `addMethod` is really terrible), and testing in Code Sandbox, I found that this works:

```js
Yup.addMethod(Yup.array, 'atMostOne', function(args) {
  const { message, predicate } = args
  return this.test('atMostOne', message, function(list) {
    // If there are 2+ elements after filtering, we know atMostOne must be false.
    return list.filter(predicate).length < 2
  })
})
```

The predicate, obviously, is a function that takes an element of the array and performs a test on it that returns a `boolean`.

For an array of scalar values, this is as simple as `el => el === value`. For an array of objects, it would be `el => el.property === value` or `el[property] === value`.

Hope this helps anybody else curious about this.